# How "CREATE VIEW" works?

Tags: sql, powerbi, create-view

I'm a newbie in here. I had a problem that need your help.

**Here is my context:** I have 1 table that contains 100 mil data rows. I need to build reports from this table. I use Power BI, using direct import, and write SQL statements in Power BI. When the data loaded to Power BI, it reduced to 20 mil rows (cause I used GROUP BY in SQL statement). But the performance of Power BI is really terrible. In my opinion, Power BI had to run the query statement, and then visualize data, so its performance is bad.

**Here is my solution:** I'm going to CREATE VIEW (using GROUP BY statement) in my database. So that, the run query workload is no longer belongs to Power BI. My database will take responsibility for the executive SQL statement. And Power BI just only need to visualize data, so the performance of Power BI will be better.

**Here are my questions:**

1 - Does my solution work? :)))

2 - IF my solution work, my database just needs 1 time in running CREATE VIEW statement, and no need to run it anymore in the future, right?

3- If my solution work, the SQL running workload will move from Power BI to my database, right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. No 2. No 3. No, it already is since you are using a query. In short there is no difference between running a query in power bi, or creating a view with that query and calling that view from Power BI

Comment: If your database supports materialized views, that would help performance, but realize that the data will be a snapshot, not live data. You will need to periodically refresh the materialized view if you go this route. Check your database documentation.

Comment: A materialized view will not help performance within an import model. It will speed up the import process but you need to spend that time anyway to refresh the view. So really it doesn't help at all here.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Import mode, then your Database is query once (at refresh time), but the view still need to make aggregation and there is no difference between select from view vs select with the group by (the view is only a nice packed query, better to materialize view or populate standard Table with the daily job);

It's a good idea to remove unused columns and rows, older than X (also aggregate if possible).

Consider using Incremental refresh to shorted your load.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview

Incremental refresh is supported for Power BI Premium, Premium per user, Power BI Pro, and Power BI Embedded datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about powerBI  but if you use view it executes the query in view every call. You can try materialized view instead of view. But be aware materialized view has the snapshot of data when it created or refresed time.

as an example the view MY_MATERIALIZED_VIEW is refreshing every day.

```
create materialized view MY_MATERIALIZED_VIEW
build immediate
refresh force
on demand
start with sysdate next sysdate + 1
as
....query
```

Comment: Be aware that materialized views are product specific. Not all products (e.g. SQL Server) support them (under that name/with specific features)

Comment: A materialized view will not help performance within an import model. It will speed up the import process but you need to spend that time anyway to refresh the view. So really it doesn't help at all here

Comment: It actually helps. You don't have to refresh view on every execution. Even some customers need a report for past periods of data such as last day sales. I said "If you use view it executes the query in view every call." and also mentioned "materialized view has the snapshot of data"

Comment: If you read the question, the issue is about performance inside a Power BI Import model. A materialised view will not help with this. Taken as a whole, it won't even help with import times because you have to materialise it first anyway

Comment: When you run reports in Power BI against an import model, the report is running against the imported data, not the database.